# Show that for all $ t \in [a,b] $ it holds that $ |y(t)-z(t)| \leq |y_0-z_0|$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Let $f: [a,b] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function so that:

$$ \forall t \in [a,b] \ \forall y_1, y_2 \in \mathbb{R} (f(t,y_1)-f(t,y_2))(y_1-y_2) \leq 0 $$

(So, for each constant value $t$ of the first variable, the function  $ f(t, \cdot)$ is decreasing.)

Let $y$ and $z$ be solutions of the initial value problems

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
y'=f(t,y) &, t\in [a,b] \\ 
y(a)=y_0 & 
\end{matrix}\right. $$

and

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
z'=f(t,z) &, t\in [a,b] \\ 
z(a)=z_0 & 
\end{matrix}\right.$$

respectively.

Show that for all $ t \in [a,b] $ the following holds:

$$ |y(t)-z(t)| \leq |y_0-z_0|$$

Could you give me a hint what we could do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $h(t)=(y(t)-z(t))^2$. Show that $h'(t)\le0$ and $h$ is decreasing.

Comment: So it is as follows, right?
$$$$
$$h'(t)=2(y(t)-z(t))(y'(t)-z'(t))=2(y(t)-z(t)) (f(t,y)-f(t,z)) \leq 0$$

Thus, $h$ is decreasing.

$$t \geq a \Rightarrow h(t) \leq h(a) \Rightarrow (y(t)-z(t))^2 \leq (y_0-z_0)^2 \Rightarrow |y(t)-z(t)| \leq |y_0-z_0|$$

Comment: Right.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Nice, thanks  a lot!!!! :-)